# JSch/Java - proper way to detect disconnected server

Tags: java, session, jsch, disconnect

I'm using the Jsch library to execute some commands on a server, using SSH. My app should stay connected to the server, until the user manually disconnects it. So, I need some way to detect disconnects due to network problems (for example), to allow my app to automatically reconnect.

There is the [`#isConnected()`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#isConnected%28%29) method. Can I use it to perform my check? I mean, if this method can detect disconnects caused by network problems, or it only changes state, after I call the method [`#disconnect()`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#disconnect%28%29)?

[edit]
It seems that the status of a connection in JSch is only updated if some action occurs over this connection. So I can't handle network errors this way. I can create new thread to monitor my host and port using Socket (for example), but I don't like this workaround. It would cause huge battery draining when applied in a backround. It's not acceptable.

I also need to notify user that server closed the connection and let him to retry.

Answer (score 3):

I have gone though the [source](https://github.com/is/jsch/blob/master/src/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.java), it seems that you can use it that way, yes. I would write a provider class, which provides the `Session` for your application, and if the connection is lost, it tries to reestablish it after a delay.

Comment: Sorry, but session.isConnected returns true even if I disconnect network. It seems it does not perform any checks. Any ideas?

Comment: You could implement your own check, using the `#sendKeepAliveMsg()` method. If it fails it should throw an exception.

Comment: I tested it and it seems there is now exception thrown. I tested by disconnect network. Weird.